# Search multiple tables with a single search criteria in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I need help with this. I have this SQL statement:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[GetDSR]
(
    @WholeSellerId varchar(50),
    @FromDate date
)
as
begin
with cte1 as
    (select co.ProductId as copid, co.DateAdded as coda, sum(isnull(co.quantity,0)) as coq, co.WholeSellerId as coid
    from ConsignmentSale co 
    group by co.ProductId, co.DateAdded, co.WholeSellerId),

cte2 as
(select ca.ProductId as caid, sum(isnull(ca.quantity,0)) as caq from CashSale ca
group by ca.ProductId),

cte3 as
(select wi.ProductId as wiid, sum(isnull(wi.Quantity,0)) as wiq from Withdrawal wi
group by wi.ProductId),

cte4 as
(select po.ProductId as poid, sum(isnull(po.Quantity,0)) as poq from Pullout po
group by po.ProductId),

cte5 as 
(select pr.ProductId as prid, sum(isnull(pr.Quantity,0)) as prq from Promotion pr
group by pr.ProductId)

select cte1.copid as Product, cte1.coda, isnull(cte1.coq,0) as Credit, isnull(cte2.caq,0) as Cash, 
isnull(cte3.wiq,0) as Withdrawal, isnull(cte4.poq,0) as Pullout, isnull(cte5.prq,0) as Promotion

from cte1
full outer join cte2 on cte2.caid=cte1.copid
full outer join cte3 on cte3.wiid=cte1.copid
full outer join cte4 on cte4.poid=cte1.copid
full outer join cte5 on cte5.prid=cte1.copid
where cte1.coid = @WholeSellerId and cte1.coda = @FromDate
end
go
```

It gives me the right result only when there is a data in the ConsignmentSale that meets the specific condition. The problem is, when there is no data in the ConsignmentSale that meets the condition but there is in some other table, it is not displayed. Probably it is because of this part:

```
where cte1.coid = @WholeSellerId and cte1.coda = @FromDate
```

It is only using the criteria in a single table, the ConsignmentSale, and it does not check the rest of the table for this criteria. Please show me how to alter this procedure in such a way that even if in the ConsignmentSale the criteria is not met but in the other table it is met, it will still give me result and the coq is just going to be 0 since it does not have data that adheres to that criteria.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Move the filter's to `ON` condition

```
................
FROM   cte1 
   FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 
                ON cte2.caid = cte1.copid 
                   AND cte1.coid = @WholeSellerId 
                   AND cte1.coda = @FromDate 
   FULL OUTER JOIN cte3 
                ON cte3.wiid = cte1.copid 
   FULL OUTER JOIN cte4 
                ON cte4.poid = cte1.copid 
   FULL OUTER JOIN cte5 
                ON cte5.prid = cte1.copid 
.................
```

Comment: It still doesn't give me the right result. I think the problem is on my search criteria. On the last SELECT statement I am only getting the cte1.copid so that means it will display the ProductId from ConsignmentSale only. But what if the condition in ConsignmentSale does not meet my criteria then that means, it will not print the ProductId anymore.

Comment: The first FULL JOIN between cte1 & cte2 have rows that match between cte1 and cte2 and rows in either cte1 or cte2 that don't match. For the rows in cte2 that don't match with cte1 (the RIGHT JOIN part of the FULL JOIN), cte1.copid will be NULL. Then take a look at the second FULL JOIN specification: `ON cte3.wiid = cte1.copid`. For the rows in cte2 that dont match cte1, cte1.copid is NULL and hence this condition will not satisfy for the RIGHT JOIN part of the first FULL JOIN. Perhaps that was intended but I doubt it.

Comment: And rereading his query, he has this in the WHERE clause: `cte1.coid = @WholeSellerId`. Meaning cte1.coid cannot be NULL, and hence his whole construction with FULL JOINs is bogus. The query will output as though the query was written with LEFT JOINs (but possibly less performant than had he written the query that way).

Answer (score 0):

I just created a criteria on each statement like so:

```
    ALTER proc [dbo].[GetDSR]
(
    @WholeSellerId varchar(50),
    @FromDate date
)
as
begin
with 
cte1 as
    (select pr.ProductId from Product pr),

cte2 as 
    (select co.WholeSellerId as cowi, co.DateAdded as coda, co.ProductId as coid, sum(isnull(co.Quantity,0)) as coq from ConsignmentSale co
    where co.WholeSellerId=@WholeSellerId and co.DateAdded=@FromDate
    group by co.ProductId, co.DateAdded, co.WholeSellerId),

cte3 as
    (select ca.DateAdded as cada, ca.WholeSellerId as cawi, ca.ProductId as caid, sum(isnull(ca.Quantity,0)) as caq from CashSale ca
    where ca.WholeSellerId=@WholeSellerId and ca.DateAdded=@FromDate
    group by ca.ProductId, ca.WholeSellerId, ca.DateAdded),

cte4 as
    (select pm.DateAdded as pmda, pm.ProductId as pmid, pm.WholeSellerId as pmwi, sum(isnull(pm.Quantity,0)) as pmq from Promotion pm
    where pm.WholeSellerId=@WholeSellerId and pm.DateAdded=@FromDate
    group by pm.DateAdded, pm.ProductId, pm.WholeSellerId),

cte5 as 
    (select wi.ProductId as wiid, wi.DateAdded as wida, wi.WholeSellerId as wiwi, sum(isnull(wi.Quantity,0)) as wiq from Withdrawal wi
    where wi.WholeSellerId=@WholeSellerId and wi.DateAdded=@FromDate
    group by wi.DateAdded, wi.WholeSellerId, wi.ProductId),

cte6 as 
    (select po.ProductId as poid, po.DateAdded as poda, po.WholeSellerId as powi, sum(isnull(po.Quantity,0)) as poq from Pullout po
    where po.WholeSellerId=@WholeSellerId and po.DateAdded=@FromDate
    group by po.ProductId, po.DateAdded, po.WholeSellerId)

select cte1.ProductId as 'Product', isnull(cte2.coq,0)  as 'Credit', isnull(cte3.caq,0) as 'Cash', isnull(cte5.wiq,0) as 'Withdrawal', 
isnull(cte6.poq,0) as 'Pullout', isnull(cte4.pmq,0) as 'Promotion' 
from cte1
full outer join cte2 on cte2.coid = cte1.ProductId
full outer join cte3 on cte3.caid=cte1.ProductId
full outer join cte4 on cte4.pmid=cte1.ProductId
full outer join cte5 on cte5.wiid=cte1.ProductId
full outer join cte6 on cte6.poid=cte1.ProductId
end
```